# TYPO3 how to derive from Richtext Rendertypes

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am often using the positibility to write user defined rendertypes like this:

TCA 
    'type' => 'text',
    'renderType' => 'myText',

my class

```
class MyTextElement extends TextElement
{
    public function render()
    {
        // define the functionality for the render type
    }
}
```

So far, so good,.. but it destroys RTE fields. After this I am not able to USE a field as an RTE ...

How can I create a user defined render type...?

regards n00n

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no solution, Comes with typo3 8.x..... Then the RTE fields get rendertypes, too.